# Jar File running SqlPlus - Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, jar, sqlplus

I am running a jar file that execute Sqlplus and I get the error:

```
"Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory"
```

But I did set in every files `bashrc`, `bash_profile` my ORACLE_HOME env variable and others variables that needed `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
When I execute the sqlplus command at terminal works normally, when I use eclipse too, just not work when I type at terminal the following command:

```
java -jar file.jar
```

I am using Mac OS Mojave with InstantClient Oracle

Someone have any idea what is wrong?

---

Below a little part of my jar file where is called sqlplus.
...

```
    StringBuilder comando = new StringBuilder();

    comando.append("/Applications/oracle/product/instantclient_64/11.2.0.4.0/bin/sqlplus -s user/pass@host:1521/ssid script.sql");

    try {


        String s = null;

        Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando.toString());

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));


        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            logger.debug(s);
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        lioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What's in the manifest of your jar?

Comment: Maurice, I put a part of my java code. See please